# Swift 1.2 crashes in release mode

Tags: ios, swift, crash, release, nszombie

When an app is built with -O (fastest) setting , crashes occur very quickly at seemingly random places.

Occurs in latest beta as well as final.

How would one track those down?

Tried allocations instrument with NSZombie detection enabled. 
Tried crashlytics and/or device crash reports but they are similarliy cryptic to me.
Started to put debug messages in the code, trying to find out where it sometimes hits.

I read here and on the apple dev formus that it could be related to core data fetches, to upper/lower case String operations, Array conversions from/to NSArray, etc.

All I am getting currently is:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x174e3439c: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Turning off optimizations in release mode with -Onone seems to fix the problem(s) I am experiencing with my code.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.